# What's the nearest equivalent of DateTime.TryParse() in classic asp?

Tags: datetime, asp-classic, vbscript

I need to do some validation in classic asp on some user-supplied strings to make sure they are valid dates.  How can I parse the string to a date while checking for type mismatch exceptions...

So far it's looking alot harder than I thought!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`IsDate`](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/13938.asp) for this.

This determines whether the value is a date or can be converted to a date.

E.g. (from [here](http://qtp.blogspot.ca/2009/01/vbscript-date-time-functions.html)),

```
x = "January 12, 2009"
if IsDate(x) then
    msgbox(CDate(x))
end if
```

**Output:**

```
1/12/2009
```

Comment: Works like a charm.  I guess it was pretty simple after all!